# WebSocket code on Android Device

Tags: android, websocket

I have written small WebSocket application and trying to run it on android emulator and android device (android 4.0.4 version).

The code works fine in android emulator but when I try to run same code on device its not working as expected.

Below is my HTML websocket code -

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="www/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
// test for websocket support
$(document).ready(function(){
if ("WebSocket" in window) {
alert("Your browser does support WebSockets");
} else { // no websocket support
alert("Your browser does not appear to support WebSockets");
}
var websocket;
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.1:8080/SampleWebApp/WebSocketServlet");
// called once the connection is established
websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
alert("open");
};
// called upon receipt of a message
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
alert("message");
};
// called when an error occurs
websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
alert("error");
};        
// called when the connection is closed (by either side)
websocket.onclose = function() {
alert("close");
};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run above code in Android device emulator I get all javascript alerts messages related to WebSocket Events properly.

However when I deploy same code to actual Android device, I only get one alert message from above code - "Your browser does support WebSockets"

Appreciate your help in understanding why WebSocket events are not getting triggered when I run on device.

Regards,
Pras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you change the server IP address, when you run this code on your device?
What browser do you use?
Default Android browser does not support WebSockets. More here http://caniuse.com/websockets

Comment: yes, IP Address is correct. You said "Default Android browser does not support WebSockets", but I am already getting alert message in  browser from my code as - "Your browser does support WebSockets". Only problem I am facing is that WebSocket events are not working in browser.

Comment: Please check the link, the table says that default android browser does not support WebSockets.
You can try to install chrome for Android and test if the same code runs there. HTH

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I saw that table initially, but got confused as javascript code '("WebSocket" in window)' returns "true" for android default browser.